# Maintaining one colorbar for maptlotlib FuncAnimation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I've made a script which uses `matplotlib`'s `FuncAnimation` function to animate a series of contour plots for paraboloid surface functions. I'd like to add a colorbar for which the range does not change throughout the entire animation. I really have no idea how to do this. The script is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as ml
import matplotlib.animation as animation

#Generate some lists

def f(x,y,a):
    return a*(x**2+y**2)

avals = list(np.linspace(0,1,10))
xaxis = list(np.linspace(-2,2,9))
yaxis = list(np.linspace(-2,2,9))

xy = list(itertools.product(xaxis,yaxis))
xy = list(map(list,xy))
xy = np.array(xy)

x = xy[:,0]
y = xy[:,1]
x = list(x)
y = list(y)

zlist = []

for a in avals:
    z = []
    for i, xval in enumerate(x):
        z.append(f(x[i],y[i],a))
    zlist.append(z)

xi = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),len(x))
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), len(y))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

def animate(index):
    zi = ml.griddata(x, y, zlist[index], xi, yi, interp='linear')
    ax.clear()
    contourplot = ax.contourf(xi, yi, zi, cmap=plt.cm.hsv,origin='lower')
    #cbar = plt.colorbar(contourplot)
    ax.set_title('%03d'%(index))
    return ax

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),interval=200,blit=False)
plt.show()
```

Line 42 was my attempt at including said colorbar. The issue here is that because `FuncAnimation` calls the plotting function multiple times (once for each frame), the colorbar gets plotted multiple times thus messing up the animation. I also can't think of any way to move the colorbar instantiation outside of the animate function since the `ax` object appears to be local to it.

How can I put one colorbar for the whole animation?

Please note the above is fully working code. It should work on the appropriate python interpreter.

Comment: Do you want to have a colorbar which stays constant throughout the animation and is hence valid for all of it or are you looking for a colorbar which changes for each frame?

Comment: A colorbar which stays constant throughout the animation and is hence valid for all of it.

Comment: you're going to want to set the `vmin` and `vmax` of the `contourf` to keep the values on the `colorbar` constant for each time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the idea would be to create a contour plot outside the updating function once and give it a colorbar. The contour plot would then need to have defined levels and the colorrange needs to be defined.

```
ax.contourf(..., levels=levels, vmin=zmin, vmax=zmax)
```

where `zmin` and `zmax` are the minimum and maximum data to be shown, and `levels` is the list or array of levels to use.

Then, inside the animating function, you would only create a new contour plot with those same parameters without touching the colorbar at all.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as ml
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def f(x,y,a):
    return a*(x**2+y**2)

avals = list(np.linspace(0,1,10))
xaxis = list(np.linspace(-2,2,9))
yaxis = list(np.linspace(-2,2,9))

xy = list(itertools.product(xaxis,yaxis))
xy = np.array(list(map(list,xy)))

x = xy[:,0]
y = xy[:,1]

zlist = []

for a in avals:
    z = []
    for i, xval in enumerate(x):
        z.append(f(x[i],y[i],a))
    zlist.append(z)

xi = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),len(x))
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), len(y))

zmin = min([min(zl) for zl in zlist])
zmax = max([max(zl) for zl in zlist])
levels = np.linspace(zmin, zmax,41)
kw = dict(levels=levels, cmap=plt.cm.hsv, vmin=zmin, vmax=zmax, origin='lower')

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
zi = ml.griddata(x, y, zlist[0], xi, yi, interp='linear')
contourplot = ax.contourf(xi, yi, zi, **kw)
cbar = plt.colorbar(contourplot)

def animate(index):
    zi = ml.griddata(x, y, zlist[index], xi, yi, interp='linear')
    ax.clear()
    ax.contourf(xi, yi, zi, **kw)
    ax.set_title('%03d'%(index))


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,10,interval=200,blit=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As usual, I got beaten to the punch by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, but I have a slightly different approach, which *I thinks* works as well.

I created a separate axe for the color bar, and I created a standalone color bar using the example [from matplotlib's documentation](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html). This requires to know the extend of the color scale before hand though.

Then I just plot the `contourf` in the animation using the same colorbar and normalization.

```
#Generate some lists
def f(x,y,a):
    return a*(x**2+y**2)

avals = list(np.linspace(0,1,10))
xaxis = list(np.linspace(-2,2,9))
yaxis = list(np.linspace(-2,2,9))

xy = list(itertools.product(xaxis,yaxis))
xy = list(map(list,xy))
xy = np.array(xy)

x = xy[:,0]
y = xy[:,1]
x = list(x)
y = list(y)

zlist = []

for a in avals:
    z = []
    for i, xval in enumerate(x):
        z.append(f(x[i],y[i],a))
    zlist.append(z)

xi = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),len(x))
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), len(y))

fig,[ax,cax] = plt.subplots(1,2, gridspec_kw={"width_ratios":[10,1]})


# Set the colormap and norm to correspond to the data for which
# the colorbar will be used.
cmap = mpl.cm.hsv
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=10)

cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cmap,
                                norm=norm,
                                orientation='vertical')

def animate(index):
    zi = ml.griddata(x, y, zlist[index], xi, yi, interp='linear')
    ax.clear()
    contourplot = ax.contourf(xi, yi, zi, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, origin='lower')
    #cbar = plt.colorbar(contourplot)
    ax.set_title('%03d'%(index))
    return ax

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),interval=200,blit=False)
```

[image]

Comment: I'd say the visualization here is correct. What might be a bit confusing is that the levels are different for each individual frame. That would be rather a question of taste and about what kind of information the animation should convey - but that is anyways not clear from the question.

Comment: To me both solutions are equivalent. I'll have to go with first-come-first-served. I did vote you up wherever I could though @Diziet... Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lazy way to add colorbar. Instead of updating colorbar object, this code delete and create all objects in `fig`.

```
N = 10 # number of color steps
vmin, vmax = 0, 10 # this should be min and max of z
V = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, N) 

fig = plt.figure()
def animate(index):
    fig.clear()
    ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    zi = ml.griddata(x, y, zlist[index], xi, yi, interp='linear')
    contourplot = ax.contourf(xi, yi, zi, V, cmap=plt.cm.hsv,origin='lower')
    cbar = plt.colorbar(contourplot)
    ax.set_title('%03d'%(index))
    return ax
```

Comment: That's nice but it changes for every frame. IMO that defeats the purpose of using a colorbar

Comment: @user32882 I'm sorry that I misunderstand your goal. Let me think more.

Comment: @user32882 Code was modified a little so that it keeps color range across indices.