# Funcanimation of matplotlib makes multiple colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make gif animation with FuncAnimation of matplotlib.

Here is the code.

However the output image contains multiple colorbars like this([link](https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/utiliser-colorbar-dans-funcanimation))

Does anyone know how to fix this problem ?

If I set

```
plt.colorbar()
```

just after or before

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100 ,frames=400)
```

, it returns 
RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).

If I subsitute  plt.colorbar() with if(k==0): plt.colorbar(), image contains same 2 colorbars.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from PIL import Image
import moviepy.editor as edit
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
def update(k):
    plt.cla() # clear axis

　　#updating Val...

    plt.contourf(X0, Y0, Val, cmap = "bwr")
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.axes().set_aspect("equal")
    plt.title("title-name")

fig = plt.figure()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100 ,frames=400)
ani.save("out.gif", writer='imagemagick')
```

Comment: Did you try removing `plt.colorbar()` from within the function and putting it outside so that it doesn't get created everytime you call update? Plz share some data so that we can try things

Comment: This is for sure not the first time this being asked on Stackoverflow. The answer will depend on what you are trying to achieve: use the same colorbar for all contours or use a dedicated new colorbar for each contour?

Comment: Sorry. I miss that question. Can you link that question ?

Comment: I want to use the same colorbar for all contours.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228692/maintaining-one-colorbar-for-maptlotlib-funcanimation/48229469#48229469

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. I solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add

```
plt.colorbar(plt.contourf(X0,Y0,charge,cmap="bwr",levels=np.linspace(-1,1,100,endpoint=True)))
```

just after

```
fig=plt.figure()
```

and it works successfully.
This method is adopted from Mr. ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer([Maintaining one colorbar for maptlotlib FuncAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228692/maintaining-one-colorbar-for-maptlotlib-funcanimation/48229469#48229469))